# HAProxy to handle multiple application subfolders in the same port

Tags: proxy, web, tomcat

I have one application running on tomcat port 8086, and also Haproxy acting as a web server, I can load the application by going to IP/appname but this application has 3 different folders.

I need to configure HAProxy to based on the URL go to the instance required as follows:

URL1 -> IP/appname/folder1

URL2 -> IP/appname/folder2

URL3 -> IP/appname/folder3

The IP and the appname is the same, only the folder changes, I also need to preserve the URL, the page can be redirected but the URL needs to be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

ACLs should be able to do what you need (take a look at the documentation to determine whether path_beg, path_dir, path_end, or another method work for your use case)

```
acl folder1 path_end -i /folder1
acl folder2 path_end -i /folder2
acl folder3 path_end -i /folder3

use backend BACKEND1 if folder1
use backend BACKEND2 if folder2
use backend BACKEND3 if folder3
```

Please post your haproxy config if it's still not working.